# How to include php files using MAMP

Tags: mamp

I am trying to include a php file using a MAMP localised server:

```
$path = "../function/function.php";
include_once($path);
```

This path just doesn't seem to work. What paths do I need to use in order to include php files into other php files using MAMP locally?

The path that works when I type in the browser is:

```
http://localhost:8888/function/function.php
```

Comment: that would depend on where you're trying to include from. ../means drop back a level, then from there move forward to function and then find function.php. is that logic sound from where this code is?

Comment: code is in root.... http://localhost:8888/

Comment: I posted as an answer. Just FYI this is just PHP. MAMP is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in root, then you would include relative to root:

```
$path = "function/function.php";
include_once($path);
```

Comment: dont forget the meaning of ../ ./ / and so on. those are very regular in coding, so knowing what they do is going to save a ton of time

Comment: If it helps, stupid would have been wasting hours and hours on it when just asking someone only takes a couple minutes.

Comment: by the way do you know anywhere that it's well explained ../ ./ / ?

Comment: kind of funny but it's hard to search for that since I believe google is not reading ../ or ./ as valid search terms. You can get the basic idea by google searching "relative paths tutorial" and reading the first few links. They are not all inclusive, but will get you started.